# Query throws 'java: annotation values must be of the form 'name=value' error

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error. I'm trying to get data from two separate tables in this query.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ConnectionRequest c " +
        "INNER JOIN (SELECT firstName as name FROM USER u WHERE c.userId = u.id) " +
        "WHERE c.dateTimeCompleted IS NULL", nativeQuery = true)
List<ConnectionRequest> findAllByDateTimeCompletedIsNull();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are providing only a single value for a parameter named `value`, you can simply put the value itself inside the parentheses. However, if you are providing multiple arguments, even if one is for a parameter named `value` you must specify `value = "text"`.

By the way, you should try hard to avoid `nativeQuery` as it bypasses both the checks and optimizations that JPQL can provide for you. In this case, you can probably let Spring Data write the entire query for you based on a method name (like `findAllByUserFirstNameAndDateTimeCompletedIsNull()`).

Comment: Can't believe I was didn't notice the `value = "text"` was missing. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a conditional subselect in an inner join

so do it like

```
SELECT c.*,u.firstName as name FROM ConnectionRequest c 
    INNER JOIN USER u ON c.userId = u.id
    WHERE c.dateTimeCompleted IS NULL
```

OR as subslect

```
    SELECT *,(SELECT firstName  FROM USER u WHERE c.userId = u.id)  as name FROM ConnectionRequest c 
    WHERE c.dateTimeCompleted IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried both of those and received a `identifier expected, got '*'` whenever I did

Comment: please post the complete error message, it doesn't seem to be sql related, as both deliver the same error , it must be your java code

Comment: Here you go

    `    @Query("SELECT c.*, u.firstName as name FROM ConnectionRequest c INNER JOIN USER u ON c.userId = u.id WHERE c.dateTimeCompleted IS NULL")
    List<ConnectionRequest> findAllByDateTimeCompletedIsNull();`

Comment: you forgot , nativeQuery = true) before the list